# Access Current Page from a Block's Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver, episerver-7

I'm using EPiServer 7.7 MVC and have a scenario where I have a local / global Block `MyBlock`.  `MyBlock` has a controller `MyBlockController`.  I need to get the ID of the page that invoked `MyBlockController`:

```
 public class MyBlockController : BlockController<MyBlock>{

      public override ActionResult Index(MyBlock currentContent){
          Guid hostingPageId = ????
      }
  }
```

I've looked through the `BlockData` and `ContentData` classes but they don't seem to have any references to hosts.

Can I get the current page's id from the controller context perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPiServer has the [PageRouteHelper](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/aae28d95-91d9-28bc-f4c9-bbf91fcbd6dd) for exactly this purpose.
It has a property [Page](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/d59a15f3-fa82-d146-4e89-d8b7660d69f6) that returns the current Page for the current request context.

So your code would become:

```
public class MyBlockController : BlockController<MyBlock>
{
    private readonly PageRouteHelper _pageRouteHelper;

    public override ActionResult Index(MyBlock currentContent)
    {
        Guid hostingPageId = _pageRouteHelper.Page.PageGuid;
    }
}
```